# How to run strapi alongside regular node app

Tags: node.js, strapi

Can i run strapi and express (just to serve static files) in the same instance ?
my goal is to run it on the same nodejs hosting to save some costs until my app doesnt have that much pageviews.

is that a dumb idea ?

Comment: The question isn't specific enough whether they are different websites or same website.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you will just have to run them on two different port.

But I think you will have rapidly to move to 2 separates instance to have a better ressources management for each application.

Answer (score 1):

Using Express just for static files isn't efficient, this is only suitable in development environment. It's always desirable to have a dedicated web server like Nginx alongside with Node.js application which is well-suited for serving static files.

It's possible to run multiple Node.js web applications simultaneously regardless of a framework in use. It's preferable to have them running as different process (either started like that or with `child_process`), Node.js is single-threaded. If they should be available under same address (e.g. `example.com:80`) this will require to have Nginx as reverse proxy any way.